# How can I make entire row submitable using jquery?

Tags: html, jquery

In the following HTML page, a table is dynamically created on the basis of JSON data passed from Flask app.

Each table row has a submit button, which are hidden from the user.

I want to make the entire row clickable so that the submit button is automatically clicked when the user clicks on any part of a table row.

How can I do that exclusively using jquery?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-HzLeBuhoNPvSl5KYnjx0BT+WB0QEEqLprO+NBkkk5gbc67FTaL7XIGa2w1L0Xbgc" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/jobs_table.css">
  <title>Protein Structure Analyzer</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script> 
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.0.1/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/java_script/jobs_table.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="menu-strip">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="{{ url_for('index') }}">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="{{ url_for('jobs_table') }}">Jobs</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="angry-grid">
    <div class="header-div">Jobs Table</div>
    <div class="form-div">
      <form  method="post" >
        <table id="table1" class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Job Key</th>
              <th>Project</th>
              <th>Input String</th>
              <th>Status</th>
              <th>Created At</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Job Key</td>
                <td>Project</td>
                <td>Input String</td>
                <td>Status</td>
                <td>Created At</td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>        
      </form> 
    </div>
    <div class="footer-div">
      Footer  
    </div>
  </div>  
  <script type="text/javascript">    
    </script>
</body>
</html>


  // sending a connect request to the server.
    let socket = io.connect('/test');
    //on page load
    $(function(){
        socket.emit('first_connect_event', {
        'first_message' : 'Hello World!'
        });//send a message on page load

        socket.on('get_jobs_as_list', function (msg){
              let row_count = msg['rows'];
              let projects_json = $.parseJSON(msg['projects']);
              create_table(row_count, projects_json);
            });

        function create_table(row_count, json_users)
        {
            let table_body = $("#table1 tbody");
            table_body.empty();
            let markup = '';
            for(let i=0 ; i<row_count ; i++)
            {
                let buttonCaption = json_users[i]['unique_job_key']
                markup = "<tr>"
                        + "<td>" + json_users[i]['unique_job_key'] + "</td>"
                        + "<td>" + json_users[i]['user_name'] + "</td>"
                        + "<td>" + json_users[i]['protein_seq'] + "</td>"
                        + "<td>" + json_users[i]['is_done'] + "</td>"
                        + "<td>" + json_users[i]['created_at'] + "</td>"
                        + "<td style='display:none;'><input type='submit' name='submit_button1' value='"+buttonCaption+"'></td>"
                    +"</tr>";
                table_body.append(markup);
            }
            return 99;
        }
    });
```

Comment: What gets submitted when the row is clicked? Is it data about just the clicked row/user or data about all rows/users?

Comment: You can simply attach a click handler to the `tbody` that will listen for clicks and then submit the form, like `$('#table1 tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () { $('form').submit(); });`, but I think you will want some `<input>` elements so that there is data in your form to submit. See: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/ocws31gk/

Comment: @76484, *What gets submitted when the row is clicked?* --- The content of the right most cell of the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with using an `<input>` with `[type="submit"]` and trying it did not work well for me.

The approach I would take would be to define a `<form>` in each row, each containing an `input[type="text"]`.

You would then attach a delegated event listener to the `<tbody>` listening for all clicks of a `<tr>`. The handler would find the `<form>` in the clicked row and submit it.

```js
const createRow = user => `
  <tr>
    <td>${user.unique_job_key}</td>
    <td>${user.user_name}</td>
    <td>${user.protein_seq}</td>
    <td>${user.is_done}</td>
    <td>${user.created_at}</td>
    <td style="display:none;">
      <form method="post">
        <input name="submit_button1" type="text" value="${user.unique_job_key}">
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
`;

const users = [
  {
    unique_job_key: 'Job 1',
    user_name: 'Alice',
    protein_seq: '123',
    is_done: false,
    created_at: Date.now()
  },
  {
    unique_job_key: 'Job 2',
    user_name: 'Bob',
    protein_seq: '246',
    is_done: true,
    created_at: Date.now()
  }
];

const $tbody = $('#table1 tbody');

$tbody.on('submit', 'form', function (event) {
  const $form = $(event.target);
  
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('you have submitted the form');
  console.log($form.serialize());
});

$tbody.on('click', 'tr', function () {
  const $tr = $(this);
  const $form = $tr.find('form');
  
  $form.submit();
});

users.forEach(user => {
  $tbody.append(createRow(user));
});
```

```css
table, td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table1">
  <thead>
    <th>Unique Job Key</th>
    <th>User Name</th>
    <th>Protein Seq.</th>
    <th>Is Done?</th>
    <th>Created At</th>
    <th style="display:none;"></th>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/ocws31gk/) is the code in a fiddle.